# Reverse upside-down asterisk triangle

Tags: python, ascii-art

I am trying to use nested for loops to ask the user for an integer and then the program will output a reverse, upside-down triangle, with the base of it having the number of asterisks and working its way down. 
It's supposed to look like this:

```
*****
 ****
  ***
   **
    *
```

The code I have:

```
def pattern():
  integer = requestInteger("Please enter a number")
  for number in range(0, integer):
    for variable in range(integer, 0, -1):
      if variable - 1 > number:
        sys.stdout.write(' ')
      else:
        sys.stdout.write('*')
  sys.stdout.write('\n')
```

Outputs this:

```
    *
   **
  ***
 ****
*****
```

I'm not really sure how to go about changing my for loops around to make this work, and I've been trying for a while, so help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? What would happen if you were to loop through the outer loop backwards rather than forwards?

Comment: switch the code inside the if and the else blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My take would be something like this:

```
def pattern():
    integer = int(raw_input("Please enter a number"))
    for number in range(0, integer):
        print " " * number + "*" * (integer - number)
```

Is this homework (nested loops are mandatory)? Hint: the `*` operator can be easily replaced by a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reversed range`:

```
u=int(raw_input('Number:'))
for i in reversed(range(1,u)):
    print ' '*(u-i),'*'*i
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been such a lang time, but i want to share my approach to the question.

```
def pattern(size):
    for i in reversed(range(1, size+1)):
        print("*" * i)
```