# Draw a triangle using a nested loop

Tags: python-3.x

I am using nested loops to create a reverse triangle that goes down by whatever character amount I enter. For example, if 8 is entered, my triangle is supposed to look like this

```
xxxxxxxx
 xxxxxxx
  xxxxxx
   xxxxx
    xxxx
     xxx
      xx
       x
```

My code currently consists of whats below, but the output is not what I was looking for.

```
row = 1
while row <= size:
    # Output a single row
    col = size - row + 1
    while col <= size:
        # Output the drawing character
        print(end=' ')

        # The next column number
        col = col + 1
    col = 0
    while col <= size - row:
        print(drawingChar, end=' ')
        col = col + 1
    row = row + 1
    print()   
print()
```

Output:

```
 x x x x x x x x 
  x x x x x x x 
   x x x x x x 
    x x x x x 
     x x x x 
      x x x 
       x x 
        x
```

Im sure i screwed up something minor with my `<= size` or col somewhere. All input is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [reverse upside down asterisk triangle in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19034814/reverse-upside-down-asterisk-triangle-in-python)

Comment: @downshift i saw that post, and took some things from that answer, but im still getting that down pointing equilateral triangle

Comment: ok sorry that one wasn't helpful. Try removing the <space> character from the `end` parameter in the second `while` loop: `print(drawingChar, end='')`

Comment: @downshift Do you see in my code where i screwed up that isnt making it what I want it. I feel like im very close and only a line or two are off

Comment: Yes, @Astonishing, it's just that one space character in `end=' ')` that you should remove, that's all

Comment: @downshift That was it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> def foo(n):
...    for i in range(n):
...       print((" "*i) + ("x"*(n-i)))
... 
>>> foo(8)
xxxxxxxx
 xxxxxxx
  xxxxxx
   xxxxx
    xxxx
     xxx
      xx
       x
```

**Edit:**

Since OP is asking for nested loop solution, here it is:

```
>>> def foo(n):
...    out = ""
...    for i in range(n):
...       for _ in range(i):
...          out += " "
...       for _ in range(n-i):
...          out += "x"
...       out += "\n"
...    print(out)
... 
>>> foo(8)
xxxxxxxx
 xxxxxxx
  xxxxxx
   xxxxx
    xxxx
     xxx
      xx
       x
```

Comment: I need to do it the way I am doing it with nested loops

Comment: @Astonishing then convert my solution to use nested loops, however, there is no point to do that in general.

Comment: I am in an intro python class and have to use nested loops and I have absolutely no idea what any of what you gave me means. I think the code i provided is very close to what im trying to accomplish

Comment: @Astonishing I added nested loops solution to my answer, check it out